# How to view Eagle gerber files in ViewMate?

Tags: eaglecad, gerber

I'm trying to view my gerbers generated from eagle (using [SparkFun's CAM file](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorial/BeginningEmbedded/9-EaglePCBs/sfe-gerb274x.cam)) as I and cannot get the drill file to import correctly for some reason.

When I drag the files into ViewMate, I choose `0.1mils` as the unit of measure for the `.dri` file and `inches` for the `.gpi` file. This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the scale of the holes is messed up.

[Here are the Eagle and gerber files](https://www.foxytronics.com/misc/arduino_pro_mini_bluetooth_relay_v1.02.zip).

What am I doing wrong? How do I get it to display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this exact problem myself. The issue is that Eagle is playing a bit "fast and loose" with the formatting of the drill coordinates, and this causes Viewmate to infer the incorrect scaling. I messed around for a while before I finally wrote a short Perl script that reads in the Eagle file and writes a fresh one with a fixed number of digits for the coordinate values, which Viewmate reads correctly.

Unfortunately, that script is on a different machine, and it will be several days before I have access to that machine again. When I do, I'll add the script here. In the meantime, maybe this is enough of a clue to get you unstuck.

Comment: It really seems like there would have to be a setting in ViewMate or Eagle to get this working. Using a Perl script to modify a drill file seems a little extreme! :-)

Comment: @Nate: Yeah, you would think so, but I played around with both programs for a while, trying to find a combination of settings that worked consistently, and finally gave up.